# List without bullets, with bold header and indented all but first line?

Tags: formatting, lists

I want to be able to have a list without bullets, with bold header and indented all but first like. Simply, something like that

[image]

The screenshot comes from this [paper](https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/tagpred-sigir08.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `description` list from [`enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) with the option `nosep` to remove the vertical space between `\item`s.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[nosep]
    \item[Increase Recall of Single Tag Queries/Feeds] Many,if not most, queries in tagging systems are for objectslabeled with a particular tag. Similarly, many taggingsystems allow users to monitor a feed of items taggedwith a particular tag.   For example, a user of asocial bookmarking site might set up a feed of all ``photography'' related web pages.  Tag predictioncould serve as a recall enhancing device for suchqueries and feeds.  In Section 4.2, we set up such arecall enhancing tag prediction task.
    \item[Inter-User Agreement] Many users have similar interests, but different vocabularies. Tag prediction wouldease sharing of objects despite vocabulary differences.
    \item[Tag Disambiguation] Many tags are polysemous, that is,they have different meanings.  For example, ``apple'' might mean the fruit, or the computer company. Predicting additional tags (like ``macos'' or ``computer'') might aid in disambiguating what a user meant whenannotating an object. Past work by Aurnhammer et al. [2] looks at similar issues in photo tagging.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]